# Scala: type parameter for a collection

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I have a function which converts an option containing an empty sequence to None:

```
def emptyToNone[A](seqOpt: Option[Seq[A]]): Option[Seq[A]] = seqOpt match {
  case Some(Seq()) => None
  case _ => seqOpt
}
```

I would like to make it more general by replacing Seq with a type parameter, so it can be used with other Scala collections.

I was able to do it like this:

```
def emptyToNone[C[A] <: Traversable[A], A](seqOpt: Option[C[A]]): Option[C[A]] = seqOpt match {
  case Some(s) if s.isEmpty => None
  case _ => seqOpt
}
```

But I had to use 2 type parameters, C and A. Can I simplify function signature here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: Modified to include @Alexey's suggestion.

This could be one solution:

```
def emptyToNone[C <: Traversable[_]](seqOpt: Option[C]): Option[C] =
seqOpt.filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

Comment: Or to simplify: `seqOpt.filter(_.nonEmpty)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I guess `seqOpt.map( s => if(s.nonEmpty) s else None)` is what he is looking for not removing empty ones but replacing with None instead.

Comment: @kali This doesn't typecheck (or rather, it returns `Option[AnyRef]`).